# Ubuntu phpstorm : Interpreter is not specified or valid

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug, jetbrains-ide

I am configuring debugger on phpstorm on Ubuntu. I easily could set interpreter's path like `C:xampp/php` properly on Windows. But linux should have different path for interpreter.

[image: Issue]

I searched on this site a lot and on google too but could not get the answer. What should be php's interpreter path so that phpstorm recognizes it and thus i can do debugging? Anything missing??

Thanks.

Comment: So .. what PHP do you have installed on your computer? Do a search for all `php` (and maybe try `which php` in console). Anything?

Comment: `pratik@pratik-SVE15116ENB:~$ which php
/usr/bin/php`

Comment: So ... have you tried sing THAT path for your **PHP Interpreter**? In case if you do not know what that is -- you have to click on `...` button from your screenshot (top window called "PHP" , next to "<no interpreter>") and configure it there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think there's been a misunderstanding. `include path` should point to a folder containing PHP files, not PHP interpreter!

Here's where you need to set the address:

[image]

As the other answer pointed out, you can find the path to your PHP interpreter using `which php` or `which php5`. Then you need to enter the path in the red box numbered 2.

Answer (score 3):

For **Linux** Users, the **Interpreter** is not located into **/opt/lampp/php**. In fact it is located in  **/opt/lampp/bin/php**. So provide this directory for the CLI interpreter. It can be seen in Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: this screen helped me to specify PHP CLI path to php7.2 executor

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it helps, but default place for php5 executable on ubuntu is

```
/usr/bin/php5
```

PS: you can find out it by typing in a terminal

```
which php5
```

PS2: I set up xdebug using this wonderful article: http://blog.elenakolevska.com/debugging-laravel-on-homestead/
 (it requires Homestad -- Laravel Ubuntu box for Vagrant, but maybe it will be usefull for you too)

Comment: php5 is Not a folder , so I can select at max upto `/usr/bin` , and still shows error. Do you have linux too ?

Comment: Yes, I do.  `/usr/bin/php5 ` is not a folder. It's an executable file (you can check it out typing in console `ls -l /usr/bin/php5`). I think you are trying to add it in include paths. But I'm not sure that you are looking in right direction. Sorry, I'm not sure that I can give you direct solution with your issue, because I don't have experience setting up xdebug with built in php server. But if your computer have enough RAM (I recommend at least 8GB) I would give Homestead a try and use artice mentioned in my answer. It should be very easy. http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Comment: I wish people could actually answer instead of downvoting my question.

Comment: Now it prompt /usr/bin/php in Ubuntu 16.04 php 7 PhpStorm 17