# 'Specify PHP interpreter path' warning when set PhpStorm interpreters

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I was setting remote PHP interpreters to use xdebug extension, but I met this question: it can read my remote php version correctly, but show the warning information like

[image]

[image]

I want to solve the problem by this answer, but it didn't work: [Ubuntu phpstorm : Interpreter is not specified or valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123921/ubuntu-phpstorm-interpreter-is-not-specified-or-valid)

Comment: Did you create a remote or local interpreter? If remote, please show the "remote" section with your selected options.

Comment: hi, I found that I have included a wrong interpreter path, and now this question has been fixd, but another question is, I can't 
map the local address to the remote address, and I use the samba to download the project(linux) to local(windows), when I debug ,it shows "Could not open input file:".

Comment: I resolved this problem, changed CLI interpreters. I set the root, previously used  whereis php. And Delete the other cli interpreters