# PhpStorm XAMPP as interpreter in Ubuntu based ZorinOS

Tags: php, linux, xampp, phpstorm

I don't know how to use XAMPP as my interpreter. And I couldn't find any information that helps. So do you guys maybe know how to do that?

I know it sounds like I didn't do any research but I did not find anything that really helps. In the screenshot is how far I came. But as you see it doesn't work. That was from this post: [Ubuntu phpstorm : Interpreter is not specified or valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123921/ubuntu-phpstorm-interpreter-is-not-specified-or-valid)

```
whereis php               
php: /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

The above is the output of where the php file is but PhpStorm doesn't seem to find it.

[image: image about the problem I am stuck right now. probably will be stuck again after this is fixed]

Comment: Please run `/opt/lampp/bin/php -v` & share the output

Comment: Hello, this is the output i get from running that command

```

PHP 8.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2021 08:28:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Looks normal: the problem could relate to the way IDE parses the output. I suggest contacting PhpStorm support to inspect verbose IDE logs. You can set verbose logging via Help > Diagnostic Tools > **Debug Log Settings...** > add `#com.jetbrains.php` line. Contact support via Help | Contact Support or submit this to a tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue